Increase reputation required to post a Discussion
This is very similar to a prior post I made, however, that was off the back off a massive spam wave that was hitting Discussions at the time.
I am, however, specifically requesting, again, that the amount of reputation needed to post a Discussion be increased. Spam in the discussion area still exists (there's 4 sitting there right now), which would be combatted by this increase, however, there are a non-small number of 1 reputation users that are posting poor content to Discussions, and content that simply shouldn't be there. Some should be in the main site, but there's a good amount that shouldn't be there at all.
In truth, there's next to no on-boarding for Discussions, and I doubt this helps the problem; there's no Tour for Discussions, and what is "on-topic" for Discussions is really hidden away in drop downs; I don't blame new users for posting in the wrong place.
That being said, I still think there needs to be a threshold, however, I don't think it needs to be high. Honestly 20 rep (the amount needed to post in chat) is likely enough; that's two upvotes, or an accept and upvote. This, hopefully, will help combat some of the bad content that endless lands in Discussions.
Of course, the discussion to make better on-boarding for the product is something that still needs to occur, but a user with a 20 reputation has, hopefully, now experienced the asking feature of the site, been through the SG (hopefully SO will be sending 100% of "new" users there soon), and therefore realise there's a difference between a Question and a Discussion.

I mean... the fact that there's no curation on it should say all that needs to be said about discussions. It only takes a couple flags for spam to be auto deleted in discussions, and yet... it lives for hours. increasing the rep threshold would certainly fight back the spam, but it's just treating a symptom.

Agreed, @KevinB, which is why I didn't want to use Spam as the main contributor for my reasoning, like the last post did.

The company does not seem interested in making it easier to handle spam/garbage in Discussions (such as opening it up to having new posts visible in the API so that the SmokeDetector project could monitor them), and they seem to really not care what's posted in them (as you said, no onboarding), therefore I do not feel interested in helping keep it clean whatsoever. It's a section of the site that has no value to me.

I can see lifting the rep requirement being useful to keep spam at bay, but at the end of the day I agree with Kevin– it'd just be treating a symptom. IMO, Discussions will continue to flounder until it has clear expectations (even as a "less structured" space) and good onboarding... which is probably a pipe dream, admittedly, given that onboarding to the main site is poor too.

In terms of Spam, your last "Not Suitable ..." flag was actually was spam. OP had a job posting, disguised as a code dump. I am all for this FR. Besides everything that gets deleted, going over those posts that are not deleted are also mostly VLQ, could've been a question with more details, etc. That said, I don't suppose this would happen for obvious reasons.

And, frustratingly for you, @M-- , you have no option to feedback to users, like myself, on incorrect flags (but that's a different problem).

@Spevacus regarding your first point about the API. I don't know if other experimental features were accessible through API. Do you know if Documentation was visible through the API? What about SG right now?

@M-- SG posts were visible during the first iteration of the Beta via the SE Websocket and observable via Smokey. SO made a concerted effort to ensure Charcoal was looped in early enough and their needs were met (which was awesome). I wasn't around for Documentation.

...but a user with a 20 reputation has, hopefully, now experienced the asking feature... - why? I posted my first (terrible) question at around 600 rep, and the next one at ~1.5k AFAIC. It's a bit weird to assume that asking a question is the only possible scenario of first steps on SO.

As the statement you quote states @STerliakov , I say "hopefully", not will have. I don't assume what you state.

Can you be so certain what is off-topic for Discussions though? It still feels like a tool to pull traffic from Reddit and not much more. I'll give an example: This post . That's your basic Reddit post; it'll attract a hundred differing opinions which will just cause an information overload rather than a state of being informed. Absolutely not a question for the main site, so without Discussions it wouldn't be generating ad revenue for SO.

That's just a bad discussion, @Gimby , there's a feature for that, it's called the down... Oh, yeah... "Discussions" like this one though, are clearly not on-topic for discussions, but might be as a normal question if (significantly) improve. The user, however, has never posted a question. I'm not even sure how they ended up at posted a Discussion before a Question...
